# In AS3, is it more efficient to consolidate different event types into just one event type with multiple values?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events, actionscript

Is one of these particularly more effiicient than the other?

---

1:

Within Class A:

```
var b:B = new B();
b.addEventListener(B.TYPE1, onType1);
b.addEventListener(B.TYPE2, onType2);
b.addEventListener(B.TYPE3, onType3);
```

Within Class B:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(TYPE1));
.
.
.
dispatchEvent(new Event(TYPE2));
.
.
.
dispatchEvent(new Event(TYPE3));
```

---

2:

Within Class A:

```
var b:B = new B();
b.addEventListener(CEvent.TYPE, onCEvent);
.
.
.
private function onCEvent(pEvent:CEvent):void
{
    switch (pEvent.code)
    {
        case B.TYPE1:
            onType1();
            break;

        case B.TYPE2:
            onType2();
            break;

        case B.TYPE3:
            onType3();
    }
}
```

Within Class B:

```
dispatchEvent(new CEvent(TYPE1));
.
.
.
dispatchEvent(new CEvent(TYPE2));
.
.
.
dispatchEvent(new CEvent(TYPE3));
```

Class CEvent:

```
public class CEvent extends Event
{
    public static const TYPE:String = "cEvent";

    private var m_strCode:String;
    public function get code():String
    {
        return m_strCode;
    }

    public function CEvent(pCode:String, bubbles:Boolean=false,
            cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(TYPE, bubbles, cancelable);
        m_strCode = pCode;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CEvent(m_strCode, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

---

My understanding has been that #2 will be a lot more time-efficient than #1, and right now, I'm needing to really work on finding various ways to make my code run almost as fast possible (almost as in the context of video game programming).  Earlier on I wasn't using the second technique though, so there's gonna be a lot of work going into consolidating the different types strewn across my code.  I need to ask first and make sure that this is halfway reasonable.  Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Something I came to realize a while after posting this was that ActionScript 3's event model is criticized for inefficiency largely over the fact that a brand new object is created each time an event is created.  Creating objects can be a slightly bulky process, in and of itself, so an event model that is based on creating brand new objects over and over again is liable to be fairly inefficient as a direct result of that.

At the time I wrote this question, I wasn't aware this was the source of cricism, or of the fact that object creation was slow, and putting it in that light, neither one of the approaches above would really do much to get around that issue.  (Approach 2 would probably be ultimately worse.)  I don't want to put that down as an answer, but I do want that bit of context to be put down on this thread.

Comment: If you need game-like efficiency, i would consider using callbacks or AS Signals instead of events. Events are pretty slow - especially when bubbling.

Comment: By callbacks, do you you basically mean circular dependencies and client objects calling their owners' functions?

Comment: A callback is a function you pass as an argument to another function so that it can be executed later. It doesn't know about 'client' or 'owner', but only about the scope it is executed in. In essence the function you pass to `addEventListener` is also a callback.

Comment: I think he refers to calling directly a Function object. I too would suggest signals as they are 1) a lot faster and 2) a lot cleaner in code. They also provide removeAll functions that helps a lot in avoiding memory leaks caused by the standard event listeners (which needs to be either removed or useWekReference, which I've read does not always work as it should).

Comment: I confirm that i meant callbacks in the way RIAstar describes.

Comment: In step 2; I don't understand why you would use the same event type for different functionality and then use a case statement. If data is similar you can use the same event class; but add multiple event constants.  I rarely use a case statement in an event listener to figure out what to do based on the event type.

Comment: Neither is more efficient than the other by any large amount. In one case Flash spends a little more time in working out which event function to call, in the other it spends a little more time in your switch statement. You'd need to profile and it may vary on a case by case basis. In my experience events are unlikely to be the bottle neck in any application.

Comment: The basic thinking there is that event listeners are expensive in terms of time; but by doing this, sometimes you'll have one event listener instead of five or 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you sure you *need* to optimize it?
2. The difference will be likely negligible whichever way.
3. Your `switch` is a half-baked ad hoc implementation of what `EventDispatcher` is meant to do. You are trying to invent a bicycle, and it is likely to have square wheels. This is the job of `EventDispatcher` to provide an instrument of adding or removing handlers, managing what handlers get called and when etc. If you are dissatisfied with that how `EventDispatcher` works (why?) - the way to address it is to either extend and change something within it, or write an alternative implementation. Trying to "fix" it locally for some particular case of a handful of functions will bring disorder into your code, making it less maintainable and, as it stands now, more verbose.

Comment: The basic thinking there is that event listeners are expensive in terms of time; but by doing this, sometimes you'll have one event listener instead of five or 10.

Comment: How will the efficiency compare between approach 1 and approach 2, regardless of how awkward #2 might be?